# Close image effect on drag up or down fragment

Tags: android, image, animation, drag

I want to get this effect on andoid. It closes image by drag or pulls up/down image in the fragment(which is not difficult) and probably uses resize-animation to place the item in listview(probably to GridView). For example, something similar to this animation: http://gifyu.com/images/ZAPISEKRANA10-28-20164-36-11PM.gif

How to implement this image effect(resize-animation)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not too hard to archive your animation if you follow these below steps.

1, you need to check [Shared Element](http://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition) to make cool scale animation for your image in the `RecyclerView`.

2, You need to implement `onTouch` for your image to get `swipe down/up` to remove the fragment (you should try with normal view first, then you can try with viewpager).